# How to loop through columns and create 2 different graphs using the same data

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I'm somewhat new to R and have tried to create a code that helps me loop trough a large dataset and thereby produce 2 graphs per column. In doing so it has to take into account some specified variables and differentiate between them (see code).
In the first graph it should make a boxplot/scatterplot where I need to differentiate between the control and the diseased cohort. in addition to that I want to see the difference between people with an event vs no event.

This is actually the code that does work. I now what to add a code where I combine that graph with a histogram of the variable so I can have some clue about the distribution of the data. I tried to add that to the function but that somehow does not work

In addition I would like to combine both graphs into 1 page and in the end loop through the whole set of variables and save it as an image (see code)

please find below the code I have so far. Any suggestions are very much appreciated

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
```

## Create a dataframe with random numbers and 2 groups

```
group <- c("Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD", "Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD", "Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD")
b <- round(runif(15, 1, 7)) 
c <- round(runif(15, 1, 3)) 
d <- round(runif(15, 3, 8)) 
e <- round(runif(15, 1, 5))
event <- c("no event", "event" , "no event" , "no event" , "no event", "no event", "event", "no event", "no event" , "no event" , "no event" , "no event", "no event", "event", "event")
```

Join the variables to create a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(group, b,c,d, e, event)
df

rm(group, b, c, d, e, event)
```

make a new color that gives a specific color the the labels (used # for color labeling the groups in 1 graph)

```
df$color <- "color"
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$group[i]=="Control") {
    df$color[i] <- "Control" # in de column PAD, if the control is control give the color the string "control"
  }
}
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD with event" # in de column PAD, if the PAD has event give the color the string "event"
  }
}
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "no event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD without event"
  }
}
rm(i)
```

pull the names out by index
create 1 explanatory variable
used as explanatory value (column 1)

```
expl = names(df[1])
```

used for looping through the columns 2:5

```
response = names(df[2:5])
```

use named vectors

```
response = set_names(response)
response

expl = set_names(expl)
expl
```

scatterplot
the first part of the functions works
PART 1 of the function

```
scatter_fun = function(x, y) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color=color) ) + 
    geom_boxplot(fill="lightgrey", colour= "black", alpha=0.7,  
                 outlier.shape=NA) + 



geom_point(position = position_jitter(0.2)) +
    scale_color_manual(values= c("Control"="Orange", "PAD with event" = "Red", "PAD without event"="Green")) + # color the values as as you please
    labs(x = "",
         y = y,
         caption = "") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid',
                                          colour = "grey"), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.05, linetype = 'solid',
                                          colour = "grey"),

          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size=13),
          legend.key.size = unit(3,"line"))
```

PART 2 of the function (which does not work)
add a histogram to the function
this is the part where it gets complicated to me. I want to get 3 things out of the function
1 the upper part that gives me a boxplot combined with a scatter plot
2 the part below where I want to have the histogram of the looped column (in this case b) to 
get a feeling about the distribution of the value
3 With the function in the end I would like to transfer both columns on one page two a PDF 
file while looping through the columns
to get an idea of what is going on this plot can be removed and the example below can be used 
to get an example
add a histogram to the function

```
ggplot(df, aes(x =.data[[x]])) +
    geom_histogram(fill="Orange", color="black", stat = "count")

}
```

example of how it works when you just specify the name of the column

```
loopplots = map(expl, ~scatter_fun(.x, "b") ) 
loopplots
```

when I run this it separates control and PAD however I don't want them to be separated but just want an overall idea of the distribution of both groups together

the whole loop: when I run this part it saves only the latter part of the function

```
event_vs_no_event = map(response,
                        ~map(expl, scatter_fun, y = .x) )
```

check what is saved on b

```
event_vs_no_event$b
```

save all the images into 1 PDF --> here I want to have both the histogram and the scatter plot corresponding to 1 column save into 1 page.

```
pdf("event_vs_no_event.pdf")
event_vs_no_event
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use sth. like this as a starting point. It is much more convinient to use long dataframes with ggplot than wide ones. Here I use tidyr's `gather` to make the long dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
p1 <- df %>% 
  gather(response , value, -group, -event) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group, value, color = event)) + 
   geom_boxplot(show.legend = F) + 
   geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), show.legend = F) +  
   facet_wrap(~response, scales = "free_y")

p2 <- df %>% 
  gather(response , value, -group, -event) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill="Orange", color="black", bins= 6) + 
  facet_wrap(~response, scales = "free") 

library(cowplot)

plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The tidiest way without loops would be s.th. like this.

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)
plots <- df %>% 
  gather(response , value, -group, -event) %>% 
  nest(-response) %>% 
  mutate(box_scatter = map2(data, response, ~ggplot(.x,aes(group, value)) + 
        geom_boxplot(show.legend = F) + 
        geom_beeswarm(aes(color = event)) +
        ggtitle(.y))) %>% 
  mutate(hist = map(data, ~ ggplot(.,aes(value)) + 
                      geom_histogram(fill="Orange", color="black", bins= 6)+
                      ggtitle("")))

pdf("all_plots.pdf", width = 15)
map2(plots$box_scatter, plots$hist, 
    ~plot_grid(.x, .y, ncol = 2, labels ="auto"))
dev.off()
```

But of course you can also use a for-loop

```
pdf("all_plots.pdf", width = 15)
for (i in names(df)[2:5]){
  p1 <- ggplot(df, aes_string("group",i)) + 
    geom_boxplot(show.legend = F) + 
    geom_beeswarm(aes(color = event))

  p2 <- ggplot(df,aes_string(i)) + 
    geom_histogram(fill="Orange", color="black", bins= 6)

  p_all <- plot_grid(p1, p2)
  print(p_all)
} 
dev.off()
```

Comment: There is one problem though but maybe it is my lack of experience in coding with R

I have 290 variables that I want to visualize as in the attachment: 1 scatter/boxplot and the corresponding histogram on 1 page. then loop to the next column and reproduce the same but with the next variable. In the end I want this printed: 1 variable (two plots) per page. I added an attachment so you can see how it should look like.